# What is the correct way to install the delta module in python?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

What is the correct way to install the delta module in python??

In the [example](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html) they import the module

`from delta.tables import *`

but i did not find the correct way to install the module in my virtual env

Currently i am using this spark param -

`"spark.jars.packages": "io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.5.0"`

Comment: See my answer on how to do this with Delta 1.2 & PySpark 3.2.  The other answers are outdated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Delta's Python codes are stored inside a jar and loaded by Spark, `delta` module cannot be imported until SparkSession/SparkContext is created.

Comment: I created a SparkSession, but still get that error. Do you have code that works?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I don't think `from delta.tables import *` will work outside of a Databricks Runtime.  You can however use delta tables, just not specific delta table utilities.

Comment: How did you start pyspark? If you run a command like `pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.5.0 ...`, it should work.

Comment: started python then `SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars.packages",'io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1').config("spark.delta.logStore.class","org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore").config("spark.sql.extensions","io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension").config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog","org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog").getOrCreate()`  Reading and writing Delta Tables works,   `from delta.tables import *` does not.  However, it does when I start the pyspark REPL as you do.  - I'll have to figure this out.

Comment: Now `from delta.tables import *` is working from SparkSession started after python, and `spark-submit --properties-file /path/to/my/spark-defaults.conf` with `spark.jars.packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1` in the `.conf` file.  I have no idea what was the issue before.

Comment: `spark.jars.packages` is handled by `org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments/SparkSubmit`. So it must be passed as an argument of `spark-submit`. When `SparkSession.builder.config` is called, `SparkSubmit` has done its job. So `spark.jars.packages` is no-op at this moment.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21752 looks like there is already a ticket for this.

Comment: @ofriman This works for me with delta.io, outside of Databricks. 

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0") \
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

Comment: Just follow the official documentation, https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#python, there is a nice example how to run it in python. You need to import after spark initialization, that is all!

Answer (score 9):

As the correct answer is hidden in the comments of the accepted solution, I thought I'd add it here.

You need to create your spark context with some extra settings and then you can import delta:

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()

from delta.tables import *
```

Annoyingly, your IDE will of course shout at you about this as the package isn't installed and you will also be operating without autocomplete and type hints. I'm sure there's a work around and I will update if I come accross it.

The package itself is on their github [here](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/tree/master/python) and the readme suggests you can pip install but that doesn't work. In theory you could clone it and install manually.

Comment: Did you find the workaround for autocomplete?

Comment: No, I was just hacking and had to put this down. Theoretically you can go grab the package from their github (link in answer) and then install it but there's not a setup.py so that's not a simple task. 

An alternative (and hacky) solution may be to just pull the tables code (https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/python/delta/tables.py) and put it in your app.

Comment: There is any way of installing the module with a package manager like `poetry`?

Answer (score 7):

To run Delta locally with PySpark, you need to follow the official [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#create-a-table).

This works for me but only when executing directly the script (python <script_file>), not with **pytest** or **unittest**.

To solve this problem, you need to add this environment variable:

```
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS='--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0 pyspark-shell'
```

Use Scala and Delta version that match your case. With this environment variable, I can run pytest or unittest via cli without any problem

```
from unittest import TestCase

from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


class TestClass(TestCase):
    
    builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
        .master("local[*]")
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    
    spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()

    def test_create_delta_table(self):
            self.spark.sql("""CREATE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE <tableName> (
                              <field1> <type1>)
                              USING DELTA""")
```

The function *configure_spark_with_delta_pip* appends a config option in builder object

```
.config("io.delta:delta-core_<scala_version>:<delta_version>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can install Delta Lake & PySpark with conda.

- Make sure you have Java installed (I use [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) to manage multiple Java versions)
- Install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)
- Pick Delta Lake & PySpark versions that are [compatible](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html).  For example, Delta Lake 1.2 is compatible with PySpark 3.2.
- Create a YAML file with the required dependencies, here is [an example](https://github.com/MrPowers/delta-examples/blob/master/envs/mr-delta.yml) from the [delta-examples repo](https://github.com/MrPowers/delta-examples) I created.
- Create the environment with a command like `conda env create envs/mr-delta.yml`
- Activate the conda environment with `conda activate mr-delta`
- Here is [an example notebook](https://github.com/MrPowers/delta-examples/blob/master/notebooks/01_quickstart.ipynb).  Note that it starts with the following code:

```py
import pyspark
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues with `Jupyter notebook` add the below environment variable

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
from delta import *

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages  org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.4.1,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0 pyspark-shell'
# RUN spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.4.1
# RUN spark-shell --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0 --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"

builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("SampleSpark") \
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = builder.getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case the issue was I had a Cluster running on a Databricks Runtime lower than 6.1

https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html

> The Python API is available in Databricks Runtime 6.1 and above.

After changing the Databricks Runtime to 6.4 problem disappeared.

To do that: Click clusters -> Pick the one you are using -> Edit -> Pick Databricks Runtime 6.1 and above

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I guess the question was related to "pure" python without Databricks

Comment: @Andrej No it wasn't, it has a "databricks" tag

Comment: I guess the tag with databricks is there by an error and should be removed, delta lake is configured in databricks out of box - https://docs.databricks.com/delta/intro-notebooks.html

You need to temper with "spark.jars.packages' when you are setting up the spark on your local machine for instance.