# Install delta lake package for Apche Spark 2.4.3 ( Pyspark )

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, delta-lake

I want to use delta lake on Hadoop cluster using pyspark. I haven't found any installation guide to use delta lake apart from below.

```sh
pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.1.0 \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

I have 2 questions :

- What's latest version of delta lake (<0.7) compatible with Apache spark 2.4.3 ? I know it should be 2.11 scala version.
- How to install delta lake package on Hadoop cluster ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For compatibility, take a look at the page https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html.
Seems like versions <0.7.0 are compatible with Spark 2.4.4+, and 0.7.0 - with Spark 3.0

Comment: I just added a detailed answer on how to install PySpark & Delta Lake that will help readers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72455808/1125159

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Delta that supports Spark 2.4.3 is 0.6.1 ([github branch](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/tree/branch-0.6)), use `--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1` and it should work out of box.

Comment: Thank you for conforming delta lake version. I will be using delta lake on Hadoop cluster via pyspark . Is pyspark --packages install package ? My understanding is pyspark --packages will start interactive session with specified packages .

Comment: `--packages` pulls specified package & make it available to the code (and cache it). You can also use it with `spark-submit` to start non-interactive jobs, etc.

Comment: @AlexOtt  Is there any way by which we can skip the --packages part. Like if its possible to add the JARS to some PATH so that it automatically picks the libraries when spark starts

Comment: yes, you can put `spark.jars.packages` + list of packages into `spark-defaults.conf`